# View ['view.name'] not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, partial-views, laravel-9

why I have this Problem please?
this is my blade code in laravel 9:

```
<form class="row g-3" method="POST" action="{{ route('users.store') }}" >
    @csrf
    @include('users.partials.form')

    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Add user</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is the structure of my blade:
[image]

-Thank you

Comment: Would you please mention that line of the controller from which you are returning the view?

Comment: in create() method, this is code:  return view('dashboard.admin.users.create');

Comment: @FZ_ZID What is the file path of the view file you intend linking to?

Comment: Please update your question with necessary information.

Comment: If your return line is like: `return view('dashboard.admin.users.create');`, then your file path must be `resources/views/dashboard/admin/users/create.blade.php`.

Comment: @Innovin @include('users.partials.form')  I wana get the form file

Comment: yes you right thak you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your return line is like: `return view('dashboard.admin.users.create');`, then your file path must be `resources/views/dashboard/admin/users/create.blade.php`

Moreover, include the form like : `@include('dashboard.admin.users.partials.form')`

Answer (score -1):

thanc you dev I solve it by adding the complet path and update forn -> from
'dashboard.admin.users.partials.from'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).